# Characters text are displayed as black diamonds with question marks on notepad++

Tags: html

I have problems to display the special characters correctly (spanish special characters), i added the meta tag:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta charset="UTF-16">

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">.

<html>
<head><meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="./docu2_files/special.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

As soon as i added a special word like:

```
<li><a id="page7">Instalación de Software</a></li>.
```

After the save goes like this:

```
<li><a id="page7">Instalaci�n de Software</a></li>
```

In notepad the codification is:

**UTF-8**

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio ?

Comment: Notepad++, and before that DreamWeaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Notepapd++, try using the **Consolas font** and then you can try one of these two menu options:

- Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8
- Encoding -> Convert to UTF-8